# 3DTouch: G-code to temporarily change probe points and Z home?

Tags: g-code, bltouch

I am using a BLTouch clone (3DTouch), and with `G28` and `G29` in Simplify3D it auto-detects Z home right in the center of the bed and afterward it measures 9 grid points. For most of my printings, this is great, except for a special one.

This special one consists of one first print with a thin drawing and a second print on top of that drawing (obviously with the gap matching the drawing).
`G28` and `G29` are not an issue for the drawing print, but for the second print where the nozzle must not touch the center (since it would ruin the drawing and would measure a wrong Z home and a wrong Z probe point there).

So is there a G-code that indicates the printer to select Z home on a different position (determined by X and Y coordinates, outside the drawing) and to eliminate the central point of the grid (leaving the remaining 8 points)?

Obviously, I can't change the firmware every time that I print that special figure, so it must be through a script.

EDIT:

This is an example of the print, the very first layer:

[image]

Print 1: 0,4 mm layer of blue

Print 2: 0,4 mm layer of green

Print 3: Much thicker and bigger print of white filament that prints around the previous prints during the first 2 layers and start covering all by the third layer.

Imagine a box cover with a drawing on top. The first layers of each print must be as smooth and nice as possible as is it the visible one. I was doing this manually before installing the BLTouch with very good results, the drawing gets embedded in the final printing.

Comment: You're printing the same thing right in top of a previous print? Are you changing filament or something? Why not just have it print extra layers during the same print?

Comment: As there is already a layer laid out on the build plate you should not use `G29` to scan the plate again. As said in a previous comment, can't you join the 2 files? Alternatively, don't use `G29`, instead [load a saved mesh](/q/15952) and raise the Z height after your `G28` command.

Comment: I can't join the files, I am going to edit the first post and add an example image of what I mean.

Comment: I could indeed load a saved mesh, that would solve the second time that the nozzle goes to the middle before printing.
Now I would just need to know how to tell the BLTouch to measure Z home in the coordinates I want.